# PostgreSQL: out of memory on Linux

Tags: postgresql, virtual-machine, out-of-memory, parallels

I’m working on a college project. The project is an image editor that allows you to create multiple work spaces and, within them, upload images and perform operations on them ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/ForzaElettromotrice/edix.git) for more information). I find the problem when creating a workspace. The issue is with the function that create a project. Here the function (sorry for some strings in Italian):

```cpp
int addProject(char *name, char *path, char *comp, char *TPP, char *TUP, char *modEx, uint TTS, bool Backup)
{
    PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("host=localhost dbname=edix user=edix password=");
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        PQfinish(conn);
        handle_error("Errore di connessione a postgres: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    }

    char query[1024];
    sprintf(query, "BEGIN;\n"
                   "DO $$\n"
                   "DECLARE\n"
                   "settingsId INT;\n"
                   "BEGIN\n"
                   "INSERT INTO Project (Name, CDate, MDate, Path, Settings) VALUES ('%s', NOW(), NOW(), '%s', -1);\n"
                   "INSERT INTO Settings (TUP, Mode, Comp, TTS, TPP, Backup, Project) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d, '%s', %s, '%s') RETURNING Id INTO settingsId;\n"
                   "UPDATE Project SET Settings = settingsId WHERE Name = '%s';\n"
                   "END $$;\n"
                   "COMMIT;\n", name, path, TUP, modEx, comp, TTS, TPP, Backup ? "TRUE" : "FALSE", name, name);
    D_PRINT("Adding project to Postgres...\n");
    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, query);

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlstate = PQresultErrorField(res, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE);

        if (strcmp(sqlstate, "23505") == 0)
            fprintf(stderr, RED "POSTGRES Error:" RESET " Questo progetto già esiste!\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'esecuzione della query: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));


        PQclear(res);
        PQfinish(conn);
        return 1;
    }


    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

The [crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIcfI.png) happens, because `conn == CONNECTION_BAD`

I don’t understand why does not happen the connection, the user and the db edix are created at the first start of the program and I have no problems with connecting to PostgreSQL. I searched a bit online and they say it could be some problem related to how memory is handled by the VM (I'm using a Parallel VM on Mac M1 with Kali Linux 2023.2 ARM64) or Postgres configuration. As for the configuration, I checked its files. And it looks like the values are right. I don't know if you need the configuration files. It's a lot of rows, so if you need I will share them.

Comment: Offtopic: Why do you use an UPDATE? Create the project after the setting and you're fine. That makes the DO-statement also obsolete, just two INSERTs in a transaction and done.

Comment: The image you show doesn't show a crash, but an out-of-memory error. You have to find out what consumes the memory. Just because PostgreSQL cannot get enough memory from the kernel to start a connection you cannot be certain that PostgreSQL is the culprit.

Comment: Look in the db server's log file for the complete error message.  It should include a length summary of all the memory being used by the backend.

Comment: Try to use gdb to see if it could indicate origin of a memory issue.